# Importing a text file

Tags: import

I have a `*.txt` file with values like so:

```
0 2 4 3 4 2
```

the position in this huge `*.txt` corresponds to the `x` and `y` coordinates of the value (in the text file). For example that `0` has coordinates `{0, 0}`, the `2` has coordinates `{0, 1}` and so on. After the
`{0, 1000}` comes the value with `{1, 0}` coordinates.

I just need to import this file and later on re-use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some fake data:

```
faketxtdata=StringJoin@@Table[ToString[RandomInteger[{0,10}]]<>"  ",{10201}];
```

The first 20 characters of the data:

```
StringTake[faketxtdata,20]
(* 9  10  2  4  10  10   *)
```

The file `fakedata.txt` contains a single string:

```
Export["fakedata.txt",faketxtdata];
```

Using `"Words"` as the second argument of `Import`, imports

> *words separated by spaces, given as a list of strings.*

```
imp=Import["fakedata.txt", "Words"];
```

And ... a possible interpretation of

> *Plot data from txt*

and

> *I need to make a density plot*

in OP's original post:

```
MatrixPlot[Partition[ToExpression/@imp,101],DataRange->{{0,100},{0,100}},ImageSize->600]
```

[image]